# How do I detect Intellij or Android stdio file modifications 'real' realtime?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am writing a plugin for intellij idea.

**How do I detect Intellij or Android stdio file modifications realtime?**

Solution 1：**BulkFileListener**

> **But** it works after pressing **Ctrl+S**. When a character was added or deleted without ctrl+s, it cannot report this event.

Solution 2： **TypedActionHandler**

> **But** it only works for adding characters. When a character or a line was deleted, it cannot report this event.

**The above two are not what I want.**

Any other advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get notifications about changes in all documents, you can use `EditorFactory.getEventMulticaster().addDocumentListener()`.

Comment: `FileDocumentManager.getInstance().getFile(document)`. Also please see the documentation: http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/architectural_overview/documents.html