# Detect Intellij file modifications realtime?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am writing a plugin for intellij idea.

How do I detect Intellij or Android stdio file modifications realtime?

Solution 1： **BulkFileListener**

**But** it works after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. When a character was added or deleted without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, it cannot report this event.

Solution 2： **TypedActionHandler**

**But** it only works for adding characters. When a character or a line was deleted, it cannot report this event.

Solution 3： **Inspection**

May be feasible, but how to do ?

Solutions 1 and 2 are not what I want.

Any other advice?

Comment: Maybe you can also try JRebel.

Comment: JRebel is a tool. But what i need may be Intellij API.

Comment: For all files or just specified file / files? I use `VirtualFileManager.addVirtualFileListener()` to detect modifications on a single file. I see that `BulkFileListener` is in a different package called `newvfs` - are these packages equivalent? I don't see a bulk file listener in the "Old" package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect Intellij or Android stdio file modifications 'real' realtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500001/how-do-i-detect-intellij-or-android-stdio-file-modifications-real-realtime)